# How do I map functions over a RoseTree in Applicative (Haskell)?

Tags: haskell, applicative

How do I apply applicative to a RoseTree, i.e. return a tree composed of trees created by the successive application of functions to initial nodes. Here's the code that I have written:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, InstanceSigs #-}

data RoseTree a = Nil | Node a [RoseTree a] deriving(Functor,Show)

instance Applicative RoseTree where
    pure :: a -> RoseTree a
    pure x = Node x []

    (<*>) :: RoseTree (a -> b) -> RoseTree a -> RoseTree b
    (<*>) _ Nil = Nil
    (<*>) Nil _ = Nil
    (<*>) (Node f tree) (Node x subtrees) = Node (f x) (zipWith (<*>) tree subtrees)
```

I am unsure what's wrong with my definition of pure and (<*>). Here's the error I got:

Error:
`` failure in expression `(Node (+1) []) <*> (Node 7 [Node 1 [], Node 2 [], Node 3 [Node 4 []]])'
expected: Node 8 [Node 2 [],Node 3 [],Node 4 [Node 5 []]]
 but got: Node 8 [] ``

Test cases for reference:

```
-- >>> (Node (+1) [Node (*2) []]) <*> Nil
-- Nil
--
-- >>> Nil <*> (Node 7 [Node 1 [], Node 2 [], Node 3 [Node 4 []]])
-- Nil
--
-- >>> (Node (+1) []) <*> (Node 7 [Node 1 [], Node 2 [], Node 3 [Node 4 []]])
-- Node 8 [Node 2 [],Node 3 [],Node 4 [Node 5 []]]
--
-- >>> (Node (+1) [Node (*2) []]) <*> (Node 5 [Node 2 [], Node 8 [Node 1 []]])
-- Node 6 [Node 3 [],Node 9 [Node 2 []],Node 10 [Node 4 [],Node 16 [Node 2 []]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types can have more than one valid Applicative instance (such as how lists have one directly on `[]`, and another on their `newtype` wrapper `ZipList`). Your `<*>` function appears to be valid for **an** Applicative instance, just not the one that you want according to your test cases (and also not one that uses this definition of `pure`).

The problem is here:

```
(<*>) (Node f tree) (Node x subtrees) = Node (f x) (zipWith (<*>) tree subtrees)
```

There's three main issues with it, given what your test cases expect:

1. It doesn't ever apply `f` to anything in `subtrees`.
2. It doesn't ever apply anything in `tree` to `x`.
3. It only applies each `tree` element to one element in `subtrees`.

This line should work instead:

```
(<*>) (Node f tree) n@(Node x subtrees) = Node (f x) (map (fmap f) subtrees ++ map (<*> n) tree)
```

Also, while this makes your test cases work as expected, I haven't rigorously verified that it's actually a lawful instance. (I've looked at it briefly and it seems fine, but I'm also writing this at 1am.)

Comment: I have serious doubts about `(<*>) _ Nil = Nil`. I haven't tried checking the laws, but that feels off.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't see anything that could go wrong with that one. The only case I foresee possibly failing is the composition law, when `u`, `v`, and `w` are all `Node`s with stuff in the lists.

Comment: I don't really mean with regard to the laws (though I wouldn't be shocked of they were violated somehow) so much as with regard to some coherent concept. Consider what happens when you simply remove that equation.

Comment: @dfeuer Then `pure id <*> Nil` would be bottom, since no case matches, and it definitely wouldn't be lawful then.

Comment: Points 1,2,3 do not completely convince me. I mean, `ZipList` is an applicative, yet it applies each function to a single item, and viceversa, in a pointwise way, effectively truncating the lists to the same length. Maybe we can implement a (lawful?) `ZipRoseTree` applicative instance, where the trees are pruned to their largest common shape, and then application is pointwise like for zip lists. If this is also lawful, the question becomes: which instance does the OP want?

Comment: @chi Those points came from the asker's test cases. I'm pretty sure we could implement a lawful `ZipRoseTree`, but I see no possible way such a thing could pass those tests.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. I missed the test cases, which do exclude a "zip-tree" instance.

Comment: I took a sledgehammer to it; you might find my answer interesting and/or terrifying.

Comment: Ah, I finally remembered why this seemed familiar.... `RoseTree ~= CofreeT [] Maybe`. That avoids needing a totally custom proof.

Answer (score 2):

We can see your `RoseTree` as a particular application of a particular monad transformer. Let's put your own definition in a module called `Rose` and derive `Read` and `Show` instances for `RoseTree`. Now we can get fancy. Note: you probably won't understand everything in here just yet. Some of it uses pretty advanced GHC language extensions. But I think it's interesting anyway.

We'll use the [cofree comonad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.2/docs/Control-Comonad-Trans-Cofree.html#t:CofreeT) from the `free` package. As the name indicates, it plays a special role relative to the `Comonad` class, but it turns out to do useful things with `Monad`s too!

```
{-# language PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module FancyRose where

import Text.Read (Read (readPrec))
import qualified Rose
import Control.Comonad.Trans.Cofree
{-
newtype CofreeT f w a = CofreeT
  { runCofreeT :: w (CofreeF f a (CofreeT f w a)) }

data CofreeF f a b = a :< f b
-}

newtype RoseTree a = RoseTree { unRoseTree :: CofreeT [] Maybe a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, Eq, Ord)
```

The great thing is that we don't have to come up with proofs of the `Applicative` (or `Monad`) laws ourselves. You can find them all [in the `free` git repository](https://github.com/ekmett/free/tree/master/doc/proof/Control/Comonad/Trans/Cofree)!

These pattern synonyms allow users to pretend
(for the most part) that `RoseTree` is defined
the simple way. Don't worry too much about the details.

```
-- Create or match on an empty 'RoseTree'. This is a simple
-- bidirectional pattern synonym: writing `Nil` in an expression
-- or a pattern is just the same as writing
-- `RoseTree (CofreeT Nothing)`
pattern Nil :: RoseTree a
pattern Nil = RoseTree (CofreeT Nothing)

-- Create or match on a non-empty 'RoseTree'. This is an explicit
-- bidirectional pattern synonym. We use a view pattern to show
-- how to match on a node, and then in the `where` clause we show
-- how to construct one.
pattern Node :: a -> [RoseTree a] -> RoseTree a
pattern Node a ts <- RoseTree (CofreeT (fmap (fmap RoseTree) -> Just (a :< ts)))
  where
    Node a ts = RoseTree $ CofreeT $ Just $ a :< map unRoseTree ts
```

Here's how we can implement `Show` and `Read` without much fuss:

```
-- Convert a `RoseTree` to the simple representation of one.
-- Note that the pattern synonyms make this really easy!
toBasicRose :: RoseTree a -> Rose.RoseTree a
toBasicRose Nil = Rose.Nil
toBasicRose (Node a ts) = Rose.Node a (map toBasicRose ts)

-- Convert the simple representation back to a `RoseTree`.
fromBasicRose :: Rose.RoseTree a -> RoseTree a
fromBasicRose Rose.Nil = Nil
fromBasicRose (Rose.Node a ts) = Node a (map fromBasicRose ts)

instance Show a => Show (RoseTree a) where
  showsPrec p = showsPrec p . toBasicRose
instance Read a => Read (RoseTree a) where
  readPrec = fmap fromBasicRose readPrec
```

All your test cases pass.

#### Performance note

I was concerned that all the mapping could make the `Node` pattern slow. But I've just checked the compiler intermediate language and determined that GHC's rewrite rules actually kick in and get rid of all the mapping unconditionally.